# Can I send email using SES but already have GSuite MX record registered in Route53

Tags: gmail, amazon-route53, amazon-ses, google-workspace

I have registered GSuite MX record in my AWS Route 53 to using GSuite Gmail, e.g mygsuite@mydomain.com.

Do I still able to use SES and send email? e.g donotreply@mydomain.com ?

My use case is to send like notification email from donotreply@mydomain.com to mygsuite@mydomain.com to notify the admin.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer from another stackoverflow thread:

> Since SES isn't receiving messages you don't have do anything with MX
>   records. Since it is hosted by Amazon, you probably don't need to do
>   anything with setting up any PTRs or reverse lookups.

https://serverfault.com/questions/435384/how-to-combine-ses-for-sending-emails-and-gmail-for-reciving/451672